# IE div issue with css bg image

Tags: html, css

I have a problem coding my website.
In Chrome, firefox ect. it shows the site just the way I want but only in IE different.
I think I tried everything and now i'm out of ideas...

I could post the code, but maybe its easier to just take quick look at the page itself.
Open it in chrome and IE then you will see what I mean.
In Chrome you see the content (6 div's) floating nicely next to each other and in IE it shows more then wanted..

Here is the link:
[HERE](http://www.vazcreations.nl/ultimate)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: IF you view in IE8 in compatibility mode it is fine.

Comment: I can't see that page... server not respond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like a syntax issue with the markup

```
<a href="#"><div class="diensten">
    <div class="diensten-content">
    <img src="images/icons/applications.png" alt="" class="diensen-icon"/>
    <h2>Web<span style="font-family:'Myriad Reg'">design</span></h2>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span>» Meer</span>
    </div></a>
</div>
```

swap the two closing tags `</a></div>` to be `</div></a>`

```
<a href="#"><div class="diensten">
    <div class="diensten-content">
    <img src="images/icons/applications.png" alt="" class="diensen-icon"/>
    <h2>Web<span style="font-family:'Myriad Reg'">design</span></h2>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span>» Meer</span>
    </div></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks man that was it! I agree I went to fast on the IE thinggy. I validated my site without errors and chrome & FF showed it well..
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm eye-balling this improperly:

```
<a href="#"><div class="diensten">
    <div class="diensten-content">
        <img src="images/icons/refresh.png" alt="" class="diensen-icon"/>
        <h2>Re<span style="font-family:'Myriad Reg'">design</span></h2>
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span>» Meer</span>
    </div></a>
</div>
```

Should be:

```
<a href="#"><div class="diensten">
    <div class="diensten-content">
        <img src="images/icons/refresh.png" alt="" class="diensen-icon"/>
        <h2>Re<span style="font-family:'Myriad Reg'">design</span></h2>
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span>» Meer</span>
    </div></div>
</a>
```

Improper nesting....

Comment: Anyone else appreciate the irony that this isn't IE's fault?